# DB and java time date comparison and conversion

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, time, type-conversion

I am getting a variable `newValue` in java as

```
public void reTrigger() {
    Date date1 = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH.mm.ss");

    squery: "select newValue from SAVE_TXN WHERE ROWID = 1"
(newValue is of type nvarchar2)

    String vidtime = sdf.format(parser.getValueOf("newValue")); //parser is another method which parses the squery 
String currentDate = sdf.format(date1);
}
```

Now newvalue contains date and time like: `'2020/05/17 18.30.44'` in DB, which I am fetching into vidtime.

Now I want to subtract this vidtime with currentDate  in java and check whether it is greater than or equals to 120 hours or not. How to proceed ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I understand. But I am working on a very old and outdated code and there are some things which i need to modify. Hence ill have to use SimpleDateFormat only

Comment: Not so. If your old code gives you an instance of `Date` or some other old-fashioned class, the conversion to a modern equivalent (in this case `Instant`) is straightforward. And if the old code requires to get an old-fashioned type back, the opposite conversion is just as easy. If that were me I would under no circumstances touch the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It’s a notorious troublemaker (may be repeating myself now).

Comment: @VrindaGoel You can write your new code using *java.time* classes. To interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, call new conversion methods `to…` and `from…` added to the legacy classes. `java.util.Date` maps to `Instant`, and `GregorianCalendar` maps to `ZonedDateTime`. The `LocalDateTime` class needed for your input has no legacy equivalent, a serious lacking, and likely a cause of confusion for you in your current work.

Answer (score 3):

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

You should be retrieving date-time values from the database as date-time objects rather than strings. As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* classes with the database. See `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

For a database column of type:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, retrieve as a `OffsetDateTime` (support for the more commonly used `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` classes was unfortunately and mysteriously omitted from JDBC 4.2).
- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, retrieve as a `LocalDateTime`.

If faced with a string input, parse using `DateTimeFormatter` class.

Your input lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we must parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(  "uuuu/MM/dd HH.mm.ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Capturing the current moment requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date and the time-of-day vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

We cannot compare this current moment (`zdt`) to your input, the `ldt`. Your input and a `LocalDateTime` object do not represent a moment, are not a specific point on the timeline. Take your example, `2020/05/17 18.30.44`. We cannot know if that means 6:30 PM on the 17th in Tokyo, in Toulouse, or in Toledo – all different moments, several hours apart on the timeline.

So your Question as written cannot be solved.

If you know for certain that a time zone was intended for your input string, apply a time zone to produce a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zIntended = ZoneOf.( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime then = ldt.atZone( zIntended ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time as a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , then ) ;
if( d.toHours() > 120 ) { … }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this :

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        final LocalDateTime dateToCompare = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-05-28 02:05:45",formatter);
        final long hours = Duration.between(now, dateToCompare).toHours();
        System.out.print(hours);
    }
}
```

Comment: please check my code again. i have added simpleDateFormatter. will duration work with simpledateformatter ?

Comment: This Answer ignores the crucial issue of anomalies in wall-clock time, such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). I cannot think of any situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do.